# running jboss7 as service on windows, wrong JBOSS_HOME

Tags: windows-services, environment-variables, jboss7.x

I'm triing to run jboss7 as service in windows.

If i run the server with .\bin\standalone.bat it works OK

But when I run it via windows services (I have succesfuly installed the service)  the wrong JBOSS_HOME is called which was not pointing to the correct foudler. I have removed the JBOSS_HOME from the environment variables because I will have multiple Jboss instances on the same machine.

The problem is that when I run it via the service it gets the value of JBOSS_HOME that was set before in "env variables"

It looks like it is caching the value somwhere. Do I nead to restart something? Maybe the whole windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I neaded to restart the machine ... the porbem why I havent done it before was that it is a customer machine handled by them and I wanted to avoid it if possible.

But at the end after the restart the JBOSS_HOME was not anymore in system vairables.